# Parsing nested JSON with two arrays in Android

Tags: android, json

I am receiving the JSON string in the format (eresult):

```
 {
   "elcldata":{
      "elapplied":[
         {
            "lvLeavetype":"EL",
            "lvLeaveStatus":"Applied"
         }
      ],
      "elclbal":[
         {
            "levELBal":"29",
            "levCLBal":"2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In android studio, I've tried to read the contents in the following ways:

```
JSONObject eobject = new JSONObject(eresult);
String myString = eobject.getJSONObject("elclbal").getString("levELBal");
```

and

```
JSONObject eobject = new JSONObject(eresult);
String myString = eobject.getJSONObject("elapplied").getJSONObject("elclbal").getString("levELBal");
```

and

```
JSONObject eobject = new JSONObject(eresult);
String myString = eobject.getJSONObject("elcldata").getJSONObject("elclbal").getString("levELBal");
```

and lastly

```
JSONObject elappObject = eobject.getJSONObject("elapplied");
JSONObject balObject = elappObject.getJSONObject("elclbal");
JSONArray ejarray = balObject.getJSONArray("elclbal");
JSONObject ejo = ejarray.getJSONObject(0);

JSONArray fjarray = elappObject.getJSONArray("elapplied");
JSONObject fjo = fjarray.getJSONObject(0);
lvLeavetype = fjo.getString("lvLeavetype");
lvLeaveStatus = fjo.getString("lvLeaveStatus");
levELBal = ejo.getString("levELBal");
levCLBal = ejo.getString("levCLBal");
```

In all cases I'm getting null values to the variables. In debug mode I'm able to view and capture the eresult string shown above. Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I don't  know why my question is down voted. Is it for presentation or the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way would be following. Please read inline comments to understand.

```
String yourJsonString = "{\"elcldata\":{\"elapplied\":[{\"lvLeavetype\":\"EL\",\"lvLeaveStatus\":\"Applied\"}],\"elclbal\":[{\"levELBal\":\"29\",\"levCLBal\":\"2\"}]}}\n";

        try {
            
            //get root of your objects
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
            // get the top most object in your case "elcldata"
            JSONObject elcldataObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("elcldata");

            //Now get sub-arrays from "elcldataObj"
            JSONArray elappliedArray = elcldataObj.getJSONArray("elapplied");
            JSONArray elclbalArray = elcldataObj.getJSONArray("elclbal");

            //Now loop through arrays and get respective fields for "elapplied"
            for (int i = 0; i < elappliedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject singleObj = elappliedArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String lvLeavetype = singleObj.getString("lvLeavetype");
                String lvLeaveStatus = singleObj.getString("lvLeaveStatus");
                //add to your object or do something.
            }

            //Now loop through arrays and get respective fields for "elclbal"
            for (int i = 0; i < elclbalArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject singleObj = elclbalArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String levELBal = singleObj.getString("levELBal");
                String levCLBal = singleObj.getString("levCLBal");
                //add to your object or do something.
            }
            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, it worked like a charm. Moreover thank you for the explanation, which made me understand the structure.

Comment: This site will also help - http://array.include-once.org/ and you can use print_r($array) to display the structure.